# Check which jackson library is being used

Tags: java, jackson

I need to run a test over a JEE application using com.fasterxml.jackson.core library to determine which version of jackson API has been loaded in memory.
I took a look at its API but I couldn't find so far any static class.method returning an instance of **com/fasterxml/jackson/core/Version.java** 
Can you advice me a way to check the library version being used ?
Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Version` class appears to be in use in most public components of Jackson, e.g.:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
Version version = om.version();
System.out.println(version);
```

or

```
Version version = com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.PackageVersion.VERSION;
System.out.println(version);
```

or

```
Version version = com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.PackageVersion.VERSION;
System.out.println(version);
```

Look for classes implementing [`com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Versioned`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.9.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/Versioned.html) interface, which provides the `version()` method.

Comment: Thank you very much! it helped a lot!